# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hide the field. When user cliks on glyphicon-eye-open, I will display glyphicon-eye-close and considering condition as true. If the condition is true then i am pushing that value into an array.

I am using below function, I have two roles actor and singer.
Both as similar fields with same model name. I displaying values based on role.

I am able to push the value into array for actor. But if try the same for singer it is showing below error.

Even I tried with different model name but still I am getting same error.

```
 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
        at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
        at $$childScopeClass.ManageProfileController.$scope.pushrolefield (manageprofile.controller.js:214)
        at angular.js:10773
        at angular.js:18981
        at $$childScopeClass.$eval (angular.js:12608)
        at $$childScopeClass.$apply (angular.js:12706)
        at HTMLLabelElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:18980)
        at HTMLLabelElement.dispatch (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
        at HTMLLabelElement.y.handle (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
```

**My html :**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="panel-body newPanelBody" ng-if="displaySingerInfo && !displayActorInfo">
 <div class="newWrap">
            <label for="qual"  class="first-heading">About You*<span class="styleatr">not more than 160 Characters</span></label> 
            <textarea rows="4" cols="10" id="qual" class="textarea1" placeholder="say something about you " ng-model="model.aboutyou">
            </textarea> 

        </div>
                 <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allowrole.saboutyou, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allowrole.saboutyou}" ng-click="pushrolefield(allowrole.saboutyou = allowrole.saboutyou?false:true)"><input class="eyecheck1" type="checkbox" ng-model="allowrole.saboutyou" ng-hide="allowrole.saboutyou || !allowrole.saboutyou"/></label>             
                            </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body newPanelBody" ng-if="displayActorInfo && !displaySingerInfo">
 <div class="newWrap">
            <label for="qual"  class="first-heading">About You*<span class="styleatr">not more than 160 Characters</span></label> 
            <textarea rows="4" cols="10" id="qual" class="textarea1" placeholder="say something about you " ng-model="model.aboutyou">
            </textarea> 

        </div>
                 <label ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close': allowrole.saboutyou, 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open': !allowrole.saboutyou}" ng-click="pushrolefield(allowrole.saboutyou = allowrole.saboutyou?false:true)"><input class="eyecheck1" type="checkbox" ng-model="allowrole.saboutyou" ng-hide="allowrole.saboutyou || !allowrole.saboutyou"/></label>             
                            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**My controller :**

```
$scope.rolehide = {
        aboutyou: 'aboutyou',
        saboutyou: 'saboutyou
    };

    $scope.allowrole = {
        aboutyou: false,
        saboutyou: false
    };

    $scope.rolehiddenfields = [];

    $scope.pushrolefield = function(allow){
        debugger;
        console.log(allow);
        $scope.rolehiddenfields = [];
        var users = {}, 
            allows = $scope.allowrole;
      Object.keys(allows).forEach(function(key){
        allows[key] ? users[key] = $scope.rolehide[key] : null;
      });
      $scope.rolehiddenfields.push(users);
    };
```

Comment: what do you have in manage profile controller line no 214?

Comment: you have taken `allowrole.saboutyou` in view and you have `allowrole.aboutyou` in your object, notice diff, `saboutyou` and `aboutyou`

Comment: sorry i didn't mentioned that. Now i have updated my above code. But for this also i am getting same error

Comment: what does line 214 contain?

Comment: Object.keys(allows).forEach(function(key){

Comment: `var allows = $scope.allowrole;
      Object.keys(allows).forEach(function(key){
        allows[key] ? users[key] = $scope.rolehide[key] : {};
      });`

Comment: please try the above code

Comment: still i am getting $scope.allowrole = undefined. So, throwing error if tries to fetch value of key with undefined value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127857/discussion-between-sravan-and-kalai).

Comment: Yes I tried the above code mentioned by you but my error exist still.

Answer (score 0):

Near the end of your JS file you use a one-line if condition, with a null. Replace that null with an empty object or an empty array.

Comment: But it is throwing error in line **Object.keys(allows).forEach(function(key){** . It is considering my $scope.allowrole = undefined

Comment: From what I see this null value is in your `forEach` function. But if you know your error, then correct it ! Also try to copy your allowrole object in allows, instead of giving reference to the allowrole object.